# Using preprocessing/alignment functions on the server

Tags: rna-seq, scrnaseq, samtools, bash

I am new to bash and the processes behind cluster computing in general and need some help with understanding some basics.

After looking all over the internet and this forum (+ askUbuntu) I found nothing that addresses this issue.

I have a series of raw RNA sequencing files: .bam and wish to utilize samtools (or others) to begin the data preprocessing steps defined in many workflows.

I have installed samtools and many other programs necessary for the workflow, however, once I am on the remote server in bash, and try and run a function over the files of interest, it gives me the error: `-bash-samtools: command not found`

When I try to install the package, say samtools, by running `sudo apt install samtools`, I get an error stating I do not have permission to do such.

What do I do? Must I bring up this issue to the server provider or is there a way around it?

Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is to [use conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html). In the [bioconda channel](https://bioconda.github.io/) we have most of the tools used in bioinformatics, such as samtools. You do not need administrator permissions to install conda or packages with it, so your lack of `sudo` ability is not an issue.

> I have installed samtools and many other programs necessary for the workflow, however, once I am on the remote server in bash, and try and run a function over the files of interest, it gives me the error

Installing packages on your local machine won't affect the remote server unless they share a file system, so this is expected.

As an aside, BAM files aren't really "raw", they're considered processed data (fastq/fast5 files are considered truly "raw" data in the sequencing world).

Answer (score 2):

At a very wild guess

```
-bash-samtools
```

This looks shaky. For a start you need a space between the command and the application in all Linux/Unix/Mac OS X applications (its complicated to explain right now [see below] just accept it).

---

Wait you are using `sudo` and thats how you are installing on a local machine. `sudo` on a remote machine will never work, because you are not the systems admin. `sudo` on a local machine is not cool (see below)

---

Anyway I need to do some next-gen and have 6 MiSeq kits waiting for action so I installed it from here:
http://www.htslib.org/download/

Okay so here's my tcsh history

```
 4  21:44   cd sam* # like I was in the Desktop
 7  21:44   more README # I needed to know how they wanted the installation
 8  21:45   ./configure # okay there are setting the paths for me - saves me a job
11  21:46   make # like fairytale stuff for a load of C scripts
16  21:49   ls | grep samtools # I wanna know if its compiled and I see samtools* ... yep
17  21:49   ln -s ./samtools* ~/bin # I'm gonna pop a link in my bin so after I type
18  21:49   rehash # 'cause I still insist on tcsh rather than bash (don't do it in bash)
```

However, the following is a bit creepy because I get loads of perl scripts in my /usr/local/bin ...

```
make install
```

Anyway,

```
samtools
```

It took 4 mins on an OS X machine, using tsch, after I just quaffed 2 pints at my  pub (10pm London time). So probability is set against me ....

**OUTPUT**

```
Program: samtools (Tools for alignments in the SAM format)
Version: 0.1.18 (r982:295)

Usage:   samtools <command> [options]

Command: view        SAM<->BAM conversion
         sort        sort alignment file
         mpileup     multi-way pileup
         depth       compute the depth
         faidx       index/extract FASTA
         tview       text alignment viewer
         index       index alignment
         idxstats    BAM index stats (r595 or later)
```

etc ...
BTW seriously, fun over, avoid "`sudo`" if you can, for lots of reasons (which I'm not gonna explain). Its a last resort and usually means your paths are incorrectly set.

sudo will be refused on a remote machine, without question. You COULD ask systems admin to do this for you. HOWEVER, I'd try and install yourself without `sudo` and your bioinformatics will benefit.

---

```
Program: samtools (Tools for alignments in the SAM format)
Version: 1.9 (using htslib 1.9)

Usage:   samtools <command> [options]

Commands:
  -- Indexing
     dict           create a sequence dictionary file
     faidx          index/extract FASTA
     fqidx          index/extract FASTQ
     index          index alignment
```

**Output** following `make install`

Comment: 0.1.18 is a truly ancient version of samtools and is unlikely to be what you compiled.

Comment: Yes you are right, currently 1.9 (above)